# What is the order of f=(nlog(log n)/ log n? Will it be O(n)?

Tags: big-o

I was wondering the O(n) time for my function. I beleive it is O(n) since log(log(n)) <= log(n) giving us N< c* n^c, resulting in lowest possible value of 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.